# Django AttributeError Model object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do my own blog using Django. I have a view to show an article which is extended from DetailView.
To avoid any trouble with slugs, I'm trying to classify the articles with its date of publication. The url for an article is like so (where pk correspond to the slug of the article):

```
r'articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$'
```

In my view I want to do this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    year = self.kwargs.get("year", None)
    month = self.kwargs.get("month", None)
    day = self.kwargs.get("day", None)

    publication_date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day

    return Article.objects.get(created_at__startswith=publication_date, slug=self.kwargs.get("pk", None))
```

But it doesn't work and I don't get it...
In fact it works when I do this:

```
return Article.objects.filter(created_at__startswith=publication_date, slug=self.kwargs.get("pk", None))
```

But it returns a QuerySet and I just want one article! ([0] returns the same error)

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError at /articles/2015/03/04/nouveau-site/
'Article' object has no attribute 'filter'
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py in get_object, line 37
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

And the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/articles/2015/03/04/nouveau-site/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'groups',
 'posts',
 'users')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get
  110.         self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  37.             queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /articles/2015/03/04/nouveau-site/
Exception Value: 'Article' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue is: `.get()` gives a model object, and `get_queryset` expects a `queryset` to be returned. Hence the error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ...

    return Article.objects.filter(created_at__startswith=publication_date, slug=self.kwargs.get("pk", None))
```

Because `get_queryset` must return QuerySet object, not model one

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **get_object()**

```
def get_object(self):
    ...

    return Article.objects.get(created_at__startswith=publication_date, slug=self.kwargs.get("pk", None))
```